# Variables pass in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have to pass variables from javascript to php. My code is given below:

```
<script>
function getValue(val,val2){
      window.a = val;
      window.b = val2;
}
function getValue2(val,val2){
      window.c = val;
      window.d = val2;
}
function sendvar(){

        if(window.a === 'undefined'){
            window.a = 0;
        }
               if(window.b === 'undefined'){
            window.b = 0;
        }
                if(window.c === 'undefined'){
            window.c = 0;
        }
                if(window.d === 'undefined'){
            window.d = 0;
        }
location.href = "count.php?id="+window.a + "&optionname1=" + window.b + "&id=" + window.c + "&optionname1=" + window.d
</script>


<img src="img1.jpg" onclick="getValue('yes','1');">
<img src="img2.jpg" onclick="getValue2('no','1');">

<button onclick="sendvar();">Click me</button>
```

When getValue function call so only the values of this function pass in href other values should be zero and when getValue2 function call so only the values of this function pass in href other values should be zero. But this is no happening right now.

Please tell me where i am wrong?

Comment: Um, shouldn't you reset the others?

Comment: Avoid globals. Escape your query input. Use `type of foo === "undefined"`, unless you actually meant to check for a string called "undefined".

Comment: Why are you passing `id` and `optionname1` twice in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.a` would be equal to `undefined` without the quotes. `typeof` would be equal to `"undefined"` with the quotes.

```
    if(typeof a === 'undefined'){
        window.a = 0;
    }
    if(typeof b === 'undefined'){
        window.b = 0;
    }
    if(typeof c === 'undefined'){
        window.c = 0;
    }
    if(typeof d === 'undefined'){
        window.d = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please refer the below code snippet

```
<script>
var a=0;
var b=0;
var c=0;
var d=0;
 function getValue(val,val2)
 {
   window.a = val;
   window.b = val2;
   window.c=0;
   window.d=0;
 }
 function getValue2(val,val2)
 {
   window.c = val;
   window.d = val2;
   window.a=0;
   window.b=0;
  }
 function sendvar(){


    location.href = "count.php?id="+window.a + "&optionname1=" + window.b + "&id=" +   window.c + "&optionname1=" + window.d
  }
    </script>


   <img src="img1.jpg" onclick="getValue('yes','1');">
   <img src="img2.jpg" onclick="getValue2('no','1');">
    <button onclick="sendvar();">Click me</button>
```